# Как скоректировать дату в датапикера?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
сами инпуты корректно работает

а вывод под ними- нет

если выбрать текущую дату - выведет 0

если другую - будет минус

```js
$(function() {

  let text_min = '';
  let text_max = '';

  function dateTravel(dFrom, dTo) {

    $(dFrom).datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
      onSelect: function() {
        let minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        setTimeout(function() {
          minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
          $(dTo).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        }, 300);

        text_min = $(this).val();
        $('#text_min').text(text_min);
        diffDate();
      }
    }).datepicker('setDate', '0');

    $(dTo).datepicker({
      minDate: 1,
      dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
      onSelect: function() {

        text_max = $(this).val();
        $('#text_max').text(text_max);
        diffDate();
      }
    }).datepicker('setDate', '1');


  }

  dateTravel('#date_from', '#date_to');



  $('#text_min').text($('#date_from').val());
  $('#text_max').text($('#date_to').val());

  function diffDate() {
    let date1 = new Date(convert_date_format($('#text_min').text()));
    let date2 = new Date(convert_date_format($('#text_max').text()));
    let date_diff = new Date(date2 - date1);
    let diff = date_diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

    $('#days').text(diff);
  }

  function convert_date_format(date_string) {
    let date = date_string.split('.', 3);
    return date[1] + '/' + date[0] + '/' + date[2];
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" id="date_from">
<input type="text" id="date_to">


<div>cрок</div>
<p><span id="days">1</span> дней, с <span id="text_min">13</span> по <span id="text_max">14</span>
</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 0):

По-моему ты создаёшь новую дату и находишь ее по принципу (дата2-дата1), но ведь тебе надо количество дней, а это не дата, а число.

[http://old.code.mu/books/javascript/dom/rabota-s-datami-v-javascript.html#:~:text=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,%3D%20now%20%2D%20date%3B%20document.write(diff)](http://old.code.mu/books/javascript/dom/rabota-s-datami-v-javascript.html#:%7E:text=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,%3D%20now%20%2D%20date%3B%20document.write(diff))

Прочитай это, должно помочь

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)